# How use debugging in VS Code

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am getting error after running debugger like

> c:\Users\USER.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.7.1\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe' '--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-vomttuky.aw4' '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-5gcky3n5.jua' '--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-1xr5gc00.po0' '--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-w3xqmfyg.lmp' '--dbgExe=C:/MinGW/bin/gdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi'

whenever i try to debug simple cpp file
Hello.cpp -

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int sqr(int a){
    return a*a;
}
int main (){
    int a =10;
    int b =2;
    int c =a*b;
    cout << sqr(c);
    return 0;
}
```

I have configured my launch.json file like this -

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [


        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gdb.exe",
            "logging": { "engineLogging": true },
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "(Windows) Launch",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

i am using
VSCode - 1.61.2
MiGW - 6.3.0

Comment: What error are you getting? The block of text looks like config data, not an error.

Comment: @WestonMcNamara there is ```Error-1xr5gc00.po0``` in  the config and also debugging doesn't start .

Comment: I cant find any documentation related to an error called "Error-1xr5gc00.po0" on the internet. If you're 100% sure that is the actual error, can you do some research related to it to see if other people are having the same issue? Currently there is very little information related to the error in this question that can be used to help you.

Comment: @WestonMcNamara actually error value change at everyrun so i dont think that might help i watched few youtube video and there debugged started just by configuring launch.json file but mine is not working.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Configuring VSCode is a nightmare for beginners. The only foolproof way is to find a tuto matching your system and version, and follow it as stupidly as possible until its end. If you are not too much unlucky, you should end with a working VSCode installation. Only from this point you can try to use your own code.

Comment: @SergeBallesta So what should I do now? I don't know anything about that thing ...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I have same similar issue. Unfortunately, I also don't know what to do. I receive in the VSCode terminal this:"[1] + Done                       "/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-oonhl4ga.rko" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-bcjgzjxp.wky". I'am using remote debuging on my RaspberryPi via Remote SSH.